# AngularJS ng-repeat body does not substitute $index in md-button ng-click attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following template defined:

```html
<div ng-app="WebApp" ng-controller="PortfolioCtrl" ng-cloak layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="margin-top: 10px">
 <md-content layout="row" layout-wrap style="width: 580px">
  <div flex-xs flex-gt-xs="50" layout="row" ng-repeat="property in portfolio track by property.uuid">
   <md-card md-theme="default" md-theme-watch="" style="width: 280px">
    <md-card-title>
     <md-card-title-text>
      <span class="md-headline">{{property.yield}}%</span>
      <span class="md-subhead">{{property.address[0]}}</span>
      <span ng-if="property.address.length > 1" class="md-subhead">{{property.address[1]}}</span>
      <span ng-if="property.address.length > 2" class="md-subhead">{{property.address[2]}}</span>
     </md-card-title-text>
     <md-card-title-media>
     <!-- 
      <div ng-if="property.photos.length > 0" class="md-media-sm card-media">
       <img src="{{property.photos[0]}}" style="width: 75px; height: 85px" />
      </div>
      -->
     </md-card-title-media>
    </md-card-title>
    <div style="display: none">{{$index}}</div>
    <div id="property_$index" style="display: none">{{property.uuid}}</div>
    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
     <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="viewProperty( $index )">VIEW</md-button>
     <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="uploadPhoto( $index )">UPLOAD PHOTOS</md-button>
    </md-card-actions>
   </md-card>
  </div>
 </md-content>
</div>
```

Looking at the below browser developer output, the $index specifications substitute correctly in the  tag:

```html
<div style="display: none">{{$index}}</div>
```

But within the ng-click attributes in the buttons and in this DIV id:

```html
<div id="property_$index" style="display: none">{{property.uuid}}</div>
```

, they do not substitute. If I surround these $index specifications with {{ and }} I get an angular syntax error:
[image]

Tracking by $index doesn't work either. What is the problem, please?

[image]

Comment: Try `id="property_{{$index}}"` for setting the id. Regarding the ng-click part, debug the function that is being called and see if you are getting the correct value there.

Comment: @NiK648 is correct, use `id="property_{{$index}}"` when setting the id, but don't use the squiglies in your `ng-click="viewProperty( $index )"` attributes. If you look carefully at the error in your screenshot you'll see the error is because you tried to do this: `viewProperty( {{$index}} )` instead of the correct: `viewProperty( $index )`

Comment: Thank you @NiK648. You solved it for me. Much appreciated! Is there some way I can vote your answer up?

Comment: Thank you @Sly_cardinal. I appreciate your answer and would like to vote it up. Please advise how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using {{}} inappropriately. In `ng-click()` you don't use them, but in other locations, such as tag attributes, they need to be used.

Correct use:

```
<md-card md-theme="default" md-theme-watch="" flex-direction="column" ng-click="viewProperty( $index )" style="width: 158px">
```

And:

```
<div id="property_{{$index}}" style="display: none">{{property.uuid}}</div>
```